# Building multi dimensional arrays from database results

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a set of database results which I need to organise into a multidimensional arrays so I can email the users their results in one email rather than multiple emails.

The values I have from the db are name, email, route_name, route_details. Ideally I'd like to group routes together based on the users email as this is their unique identifier. I think something like the following would work for me.

```
    Array
    (
       [email@email.com] => Array
                          (
                            [0] => name
                            [1] => Array
                                 (
                                   [0] => route_name
                                   [1] => route_details
                                 )
                             [2] => Array
                                 (
                                   [0] => route_name
                                   [1] => route_details
                                 )
                           )
       [email2@email2.com] => Array
                          (
                            [0] => name
                            [1] => Array
                                 (
                                   [0] => route_name
                                   [1] => route_details
                                 )
                            [2] => Array
                                 (
                                   [0] => route_name
                                   [1] => route_details
                                 )
                            [3] => Array
                                 (
                                   [0] => route_name
                                   [1] => route_details
                                 )

                           )
    )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated I have tried the following inside my result loop but I am not sure of how to group the results based on email and I don't think this is exactly what I need.

```
    $routeArray = array($data->email ,array($data->route_name, $data->route_details));

    $userEmailArray[] = $flightArray;
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide table definition. SQL query has lot to do with these sort of operation.

Comment: What's `$flightArray` contain?  Try `$userEmailArray[$data->email][] = array($data->route_name, $data->route_details);`

Comment: sorry $flightArray should read $routeArray. The SQL joins from about 3 other tables but the values are id, name, email, route_name, route_details for every result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following will work for you. This code will add key names instead of numeric indexes.

```
// Add order by email clause
$sql = "select name, email, route_name, route_details from YOUR SQL QUERY ORDER BY    email";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$desired_format = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $tmp = array('route_name'=>$row['route_name'],'route_details'=>$row['route_details']);
    $desired_format[$row['email']]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $desired_format[$row['email']][] = $tmp;
}
```